# Streaming audio from a Node.js server to HTML5 <audio> tag

Tags: streaming, node.js, audio-streaming, shoutcast, html5-audio

I've been experimenting with binary streams in Node.js, and much to my amazement do actually have a working demo of taking a Shoutcast stream using node-radio-stream and pushing it into a HTML5  element using chunked encoding. But it only works in Safari!

Here is my server code:

```
var radio = require("radio-stream");
var http = require('http');
var url = "http://67.205.85.183:7714";
var stream = radio.createReadStream(url);

var clients = [];

stream.on("connect", function() {
  console.error("Radio Stream connected!");
  console.error(stream.headers);
});


// When a chunk of data is received on the stream, push it to all connected clients
stream.on("data", function (chunk) {
    if (clients.length > 0){
        for (client in clients){
            clients[client].write(chunk);
        };
    }
});

// When a 'metadata' event happens, usually a new song is starting.
stream.on("metadata", function(title) {
  console.error(title);
});

// Listen on a web port and respond with a chunked response header. 
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200,{
        "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });
    // Add the response to the clients array to receive streaming
    clients.push(res);
    console.log('Client connected; streaming'); 
});
server.listen("8000", "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

My client code is simply:

```
<audio controls src="http://localhost:8000/"></audio>
```

This works fine in Safari 5 on the Mac, but doesn't seem to do anything in Chrome or Firefox. Any ideas?

Possible candidates including encoding issues, or just partially-implemented HTML5 features...

Comment: Did you ever get this up & running?

Comment: Yes, check out Nate's answer below for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a silly question, but where does the clients array come into play?  I'm trying to replicate this and seem to be struggling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Here's a (slightly outdated) summary of the current status of HTML5 Audio and Icecast streams](https://web.archive.org/web/20110902015529/http://www.trygve-lie.com:80/blog/entry/html_5_audio_element_and).

As you can see, a MP3 source only seems to work in Safari (and possibly IE9). You might need to experiment with some server-side transcoding (with *ffmpeg* or *mencoder*) to OGG Vorbis. I'm pretty sure I was able to get Chrome to behave properly when I was sending Vorbis data.

Firefox was still being a brat though, maybe it doesn't like the chunked encoding (all SHOUTcast servers respond with a `HTTP/1.0` version response, which hadn't defined `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` yet). Try sending a `Transfer-Encoding: identity` response header with the OGG stream to disable `chunked`, and Firefox MIGHT work. I haven't tested this.

Let me know how it goes! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking out FFMpeg now to give it a try.

Comment: I was able to mess around with this a bit last night, and was actually able to get Chrome to play the transcoded OGG Vorbis data! It seemed that `ffmpeg` couldn't make a proper OGG file from the MP3 stream, but Chrome was still able to play it.

I'm also experimenting with invoking `lame` and `oggenc` manually, and result seem promising (a nice compliant OGG file). I suspect that Firefox will work with this kind of stream as well.

I'll try to make an updated example in the `node-radio-stream` repo soon!

Comment: Awesome! I just noticed the update on the node list - this is really nice!

Comment: For anybody stumbling upon these posts in the future, my `node-radio-stream` module has been renamed to `node-icecast-stack`: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-icecast-stack

Comment: And once again, now `node-icecast-stack` has now been renamed to simply `node-icecast`: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-icecast

Comment: @TooTallNate and now it's just `node-icy`, eh?

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions for H5 audio only **live streaming**:

- HLS or LLHLS: The best compatibility, for Safari, Android, iOS. Now with [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), Chrome is also able to play HLS by [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js). Note that the latency is about 10s or larger for audio only stream.
- HTTP-MP3: It's also widely supported solution, but because mp3 codec is used less and less, now aac and opus is much popular in H5. So, it is **NOT** recommend to use HTTP-MP3.
- HTTP-AAC: It's supported by H5 browser, but generally not supported by CDN, so it's OK if you build your own server, but **NOT** if need a CDN.
- HTTP-FLV or HTTP-TS: Use [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) or [mpegts.js](https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js) by [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API). The latency is lower than HLS, and it's possible to use AAC codec, so it's a good solution also.
- WebRTC: Yep, it's also possible to play the audio only stream by WebRTC.

> Note: Opus is also available by HTTP-OGG, but ogg is not support by all browsers, and CDN does not support it, so it's **NOT** recommend.

Let's take a view for your stream source, however you didn't mention about it:

- If use H5 to publish your stream, only WebRTC is available now.
- If use IP camera, you must pull RTSP stream then covert to RTMP by FFmpeg, as such.
- If use OBS, both RTMP or SRT is OK.

So the best solution maybe use a server([SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)) to convert your stream for player:

```
publisher(WebRTC, OBS, FFmpeg) 
    --RTMP/WebRTC--> Server(SRS) 
        --HLS/HTTP-FLV/WebRTC--> player(H5 audio)
```

Comment: "but there is no stream like HTTP-AAC or HTTP-OPUS"  This is wrong.  AAC is encapsulated nicely in ADTS, which has been supported by all the common browsers for a decade or so.  And, Opus drops in fine with Ogg or WebM.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your correction. AAC/ADTS is supported by browsers, by HLS， HTTP-FLV, HTTP-TS and HTTP-AAC. Ogg or WebM is not support by all H5 player, so I think it maybe not a good solution.

Comment: @Brad For HTTP-AAC, I think H5 support it, but generally AAC/ADTS is carried by HLS/HTTP-FLV/HTTP-TS streaming, especially to use CDN to deliver it. So I think HTTP-AAC is not a good solution.

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of internet radio stations streaming AAC with ADTS over HTTP would disagree with you.  I assure you, it works fine.  :-)  And then, there's no overhead with segmented methods such as HLS.  No unnecessary added latency.  The only benefit is that you get to use file/blob-based CDNs.  And nowadays we come full circle with "low latency" HLS, where we just push the packets straight on through to the client anyway.  But, that last bit is a rant for another day...

Comment: @Brad Thanks ^_^ Could you please show me a website using HTTP-AAC? Just to confirm how to use file/block-based CDN to deliver it,  for live streaming.

Comment: http://dir.xiph.org/codecs/AAC

Comment: And, I meant in my comment above... the only benefit to these segmented protocols such as HLS/DASH is that you can use file/blob-based CDNs.  For regular progressive HTTP streams, you need compatible CDNs, which are much more rare.

Comment: @Brad Got it. Really thank you for your comment, HTTP-AAC is support by H5 browser, I will update my answer to identify that. And it make sense, the HLS/DASH is friendly for CDN, while HTTP live streaming is not. I think it's possible to use MSE to play HTTP-AAC, just like flv.js do.

Comment: You could use MSE, sure, but there's no need to.  Simply set the stream URL to the audio element's `src` attribute.