# Capturing Microphone Using Html 5 and broadcast using socket.io

Tags: html, webkit, websocket, socket.io, audio-capture

I am currently developing Virtual Classroom with whiteboard,video/audio conferencing. How can I capture microphone using HTML5,Javascript. How can i create base64 encoded string from microphone ? I already capture video image from  tag and draw on canvas and received base64 encoded string and broadcast to all students and its works. is any similar way for audio  tag also ? i would like to broadcast teacher microphone voice to whole class using socket.io. I found number of tutorial but every body explain about video not audio :( . I am using Chrome -v 21 and able to use webkit. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The [Stream API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html) should allow you to do this but unfortunately it's [not supported](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html) in any of the current (stable) browsers. You could download the [nightly build of Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akabngbddgpigiemjhkblleffkbpmpfc) which definitely includes some support for the API, though how complete I'm not sure.

I'm guessing it shouldn't be too long until plugins for node start appearing to help with the handling of this stuff on the server side, but meantime the following might be useful:

1. [Streaming audio from a Node.js server to HTML5  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955103/streaming-audio-from-a-node-js-server-to-html5-audio-tag)
2. [A Node.js module for parsing and/or injecting metadata into SHOUTcast/Icecast radio streams.](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-icecast-stack)
3. [Streaming audio using Firefox Audio Data API + Node.js + WebSocket + Redis Pub/Sub](https://github.com/kulikala/AudioStream)

Comment: After a long research i didn't found solution regarding audio sample data recording using html 5. I found all forums about pre define audio clip streaming not microphone sample data streaming in real time. I am wonder if html 5 can only capture audio sample data with video element. I found some plugins which records audio using flash microphone plugin, but i want same in html 5. Your comments will help full :) 
Thank you

Comment: Here is my code:
<script>
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, function(s){
  audio.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(s);
   console.log(s);
      
   });
</script>

how can i console.log real time streaming data ? if i should use timer then how ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112367

This issue is being worked making it stable for windows platform too, but working on Mac.

Comment: This is a helpful link, but it would be better as comment on the question rather than an answer, since it doesn't actually provide a solution.

Comment: It's not irony; it's a privilege to be earned.